# How to use a python function with the principal python script

Tags: python, subprocess, call

I would like créate a function with another python script in the principal python script.  this function generate a variable and how to use it in principal script

load a fonction

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["python", "myscript.py"])
subprocess.call(["python", "myscript2.py"])
```

ty

Comment: Why not simply `import` the other python script?

Comment: @jme ? i dont no understand

Comment: It sounds like you're defining a function (let's call it `foo`) in `myscript2.py`, and you want to be able to use that function in `myscript.py`. Your thought process is that you'll run `python myscript2.py` from `myscript.py` and save the result, but it is likely that you could simply write `import myscript2; myscript2.foo()` in `myscript.py` to achieve the same result.

Comment: It would work if the script is not present on the  script root folder

Comment: Then bundle them as a package or append the directory containing them to `sys.path`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Popen.communicate` in `subprocess` to get returns from `subprocess`. Like this:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen(['python', 'myscript.py', 'olink'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
output, err = p.communicate(b"input data that is passed to subprocess' stdin")
print output
```

`Popen.communicate` interacts with process: Send data to `stdin`. Read data from `stdout` and `stderr`, until end-of-file is reached.

So in your python script, you can print your variable to the `stdout` and use this to get its value.

Or you can simply write content of that variable to a file and in the main process, read it from that file.

Hope it helps.

Comment: i forgot one details the script requires an argument ` p = Popen(['python', 'myscript.py' , olink] is correct ?`

Comment: on the script with fonction He(It) has something to make. ?

Comment: @parcal Sorry, I didn't get what you mean.

Comment: @parcal As I said, you need to print the content to the stdout so that this code could get the output.